# FOR LOOP Multiple Generators

Tags: scala

Problems understanding how the code below works. I am new to Scala and have been learning the language for 2 weeks now.

```
for (i <- 1 to 3; j <- 1 to 3) print((10 * i + j) + " ")
```

it prints `11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33`. Does it assign each value in turn i.e.

```
i = 1

j = 0
```

or does the values get assigned each time it loops i.e.

```
i = 1

j = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is from 1 to 3

```
print((10 * i + j) + " ")
```

Is equivalent to

```
val tmp = (10*i)+j //* is higher than +
print(tmp + " ")
```

Your code result :

```
For i=1, j=1 --> 11
    i=1' j=2 --> 12
    . .
    . .
    i=2, j=1 --> 21
    . .
    i=2, j=3 --> 23
    . .
    i=3, j=3 --> 33
```

Answer (score 9):

It's just nested loop for `j`.
So, for each assigned value of `i`, all values of `j` are iterated.

```
for (i <- 1 to 3) {
  for (j <- 1 to 3) {
    print((10 * i + j) + " ")
  }
}
```

Because a `for` loop expands to `foreach`, your code is also equivalent to:

```
(1 to 3).foreach { i =>
  (1 to 3).foreach { j =>
    print((10 * i + j) + " ")
  }
}
```

Maybe in this form, it's more easy to see.